# App keeps telling me to join the Meta

Tags: bug, ios-app

Every time I open the iOS app and go to the Meta site, it won’t initially let me vote or comment and instead show this pop-up.

[image]

If I click “Join Site”, everything goes back to normal. However, it’s annoying that I have to do this every time, since I’m already a member of the site.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,5)
- OS Version: Version 13.3 (Build 17C54)

Comment: Switch to Android! :-)

Comment: @Asaf Android is worse. I posted on meta SE about it. I can't upvote comments on Math meta.

Comment: @Matt: Truth be told, I only use the app to notify me on new comments. I then promptly open the browser, which is set to "full site" and "disabled responsive design" modes. Because as far as I can tell, that is the only reasonable way to use the site.

Comment: Same problem, also on iOS.

Comment: @Asaf How do you turn off responsive?

Comment: @Matt: Bottom of the page "Disable responsiveness"